# Can the word "settings" be used in singular form to mean "parameter"?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number

Take for example Google Chrome browser's settings. There are a lot of parameters (?) there. Or one could probably say, "a lot of settings." But can one refer to some particular parameter using the word "setting"? Like in,

> The "On startup" setting lets you choose what you see after starting up the browser.

Or,

> The 'Always show the bookmark bar' setting is self-explanatory.

What term would be best in this case?

Comment: Both these dictionary entries have examples of "setting" used in the singular: [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/setting); [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/setting).  Please do some research first, and *then* ask a question explaining why your research didn't give you a sufficient answer.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say *Take for example Google Chrome browser's **settings**.* Presumably you know what you mean by "settings" there. Obviously a single one of them (such as the user-configurable stored parameter value saying whether the bookmark bar will always be shown) is a ***setting***.

Comment: If the application uses the term *settings* for the collection, you should use *setting* for one of them.  (But beware that you may just be talking about a subset of *settings* vs an individual one.)  Likewise, if the application uses *parameters* you should refer to an individual one as a *parameter*.  Neither *parameter* nor *setting* has any "odd" properties with regard to pluralization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word setting *is* in common use. And regarding your question, it is arguably preferable (by orders of magnitude) to the use of parameter.

After looking through [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/setting), [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/setting), and [Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/setting), I did not find a suitable definition for *setting* (which would have included its plural form) from which I might derive a good answer. However, it is commonly used in the singular: consider that Google indicates that there are 16,100 results for ["default browser setting"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22default%20browser%20setting%22) while it only lists 620 for ["default browser parameter"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22default%20browser%20parameter%22). However, while it is arguably a singular setting (and I would not use the word "settings" when instructing someone to change their default browser) Google lists 88,400 results for ["default browser setting**s**"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22default%20browser%20settings%22).

Comment: "Default browser setting" is rather related to setting the browser as a default one, than to single browser setting.

Comment: I am embarrassed to say, I completely missed that. Yes, I believe that that is exactly right, @SergeyChupov.